# Is the Question Correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Question:

> Let $R$ be a relation on set of natural numbers such that $$R={(x,y)|2x+3y }$$  Find  domain and co-domain of $R$ and $R^{-1}$.

I'm not sure if this can be solved as there should be a condition, and $2x+3y$ is not a condition. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You're right: $\{(x,y)\mid 2x+3y\}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and yes i was thinking the same.